# Networkdevice Identification C#

Tags: c#, .net, ping

In my C# WPF Program I am currently working on a solution for a very destinct problem.
The Programm is designed to configure specific network devices with a US-Hub that contains around 15-25 USB ethernet adapters. I have got the configuration of said Adapters working and now I would like to check if said Devices are pingable after I have changed the IP-Addresses.

If we think of `192.168.1.254` as the Address my network devices now all have and `192.168.1.100-105`
as my address Range for my ethernet adapters. With Windows command promt this is easy to check. I would do
`ping 192.168.1.254 /S 192.168.1.100` ...

I want to do this in C# using .Net Framework 4.7.2

I have had multiple attempts at this, since the Ping class and the following PingReply class, to my knowledge,  both dont have a "source ip" option anywhere.

I build a Ping Wrapper and used the Modified PingReply class that i found here https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/828234/Ping-over-specific-Interface-with-IcmpSendEchoEx?loginkey=false.

Both of these have a fatal flaw for my use case though.
When I keep on pinging with them when either the interface or the destination doesnt (yet) exist.
I randomly get the wrong results. I.E. if I start the ping to early and the Ping keeps on going it might randomly give me a "succesfull Ping from 0.0.0.0".

My code looks something like this:

```
        internal Task<bool> CheckPing(IPAddress src, IPAddress dest, NetworkInterface iFace) => Task.Run( async() =>
        {
            IPAddress source = src;
            IPAddress destination = dest;
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = iFace;
            var rightView = views.Find(view => view.NetworkIface.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString() == networkInterface.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString());
            int cnt = 0;
            wanted = true;
            while (wanted && cnt < 2)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    var x = await Task.Run(() => WpfForm.PingReply.Send(source, destination));

                    if (x.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        rightView.SomethingConnected = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cnt++;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Nothing is connected to this interface");
                    rightView.SomethingConnected = false;
                }
            }
            rightView.SomethingConnected = false;

            return false;
        });
```

In this case it utelizes the overidden PingReply Method that I have linked. But I have gotten the same results wether it was with the actual PING.EXE from Windows or any other combination of ideas I have had.

The problem with this, is that in my use case **THIS CANNOT BE RANDOM** I have to have definite answer to my question if a switch is connected to this interface or not.

Any Ideas are appreciated since I really don´t know what else to try In order to make this work.

Comment: Why are you using a count of 2?  It sound like you were failing so you increased the count.  Ping should always work with a count of 1.  So it sounds like your Ping Time Out is too small.  You also may have routing loops that is giving unreliable results.  Check you interface masks.  Is the Ping using IP or Computer Names.  If you are using Names than the DNS Server that is used to get the IP from the names is not returning the results quickly.

Comment: ".Net Framework 2.7.2" - no such thing, so far as I can recollect (and if there was, it'd be about a decade out of date and unsupported). First, work out what you're actually using.

Comment: @jdweng Well in this case I wanted to see if overlapping it infinitely was the issue. I think the standard ping timeout is pretty high with this one so that is definetly not the issue here. All the Networking settings are good i always check with pings by hand

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no Idea why this happens, but this seems to be fixing it!

```
var x = await Task.Run(() => WpfForm.PingReply.Send(source, destination , 2500));
if (x.IpAddress.ToString() == destination.ToString() 
      || x.IpAddress.ToString() == source.ToString())

{

   // Do other stuff

}
```

I am aware that I don´t actually need to check the source, but this seemed to minimize the margin of error even more so w/e.

Using the before mentioned PingReply class.